# How to add sound effects to floatanimation in delphi firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal, rad-studio

I have created a game that basically add the numbers in the blocks to each other by dragging them on top of each other. It works great. But I would like to add sound effects to the drag and drop move that is being done with the floatanimation feature of the button. I couldnt see an event or a property that handles this action.

How could I include a sound effect to the floatanimation of the pressing, draggin and dropping of an object (such as button) ?

Thank you.

Raf.

Answer (score 0):

try using TMediaPlayer, before you start your TFloatAnimation